# Unit testing-Sort Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a method that sorts an array of numbers in ascending order and I want to test this method. I created two unit tests, one that loops through all the elements and asserts that the current element is less than the one coming after, and another method that asserts that the sorted array has the same elements as another sorted array I create myself.

Is there any other way to test this method or those two are fine?

I am working with java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also add tests to cover the desired behaviour when:

- the input array is null
- the input array is empty or has a single element

However, unless you have a good reason, you should probably be using the built-in [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) rather than implementing your own sort.

Comment: But if I give a null array, how then can I test the sorting method?

Comment: Your test should check that the method either throws a suitable exception (e.g. IllegalArgumentException) or returns a suitable value (e.g. null or an empty array), whichever is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you by *"the sorted array has the same elements"* mean that the sorted array has the some number of occurrences for each element, then those two tests are sufficient. (An array such as `{ 1, 1, 2 }` should not be a valid result for the input `{2, 1, 2}`.) Another way of expressing it is that the result should be a permutation of the input.

A third requirement which may or may not interest you is whether or not the algorithm is [**stable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). In that case you should add a test that makes sure that any two equal elements in the input have the same relative order in the output.

Comment: For the third requirement I have included it this way:
assertTrue(array[i] <= array[i+1]). Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, not really. But if your array contains numbers (or any primitive value for that matter) then the stability requirement doesn't apply to your case.

Answer (score 2):

1. check with null array.
2. check with Integer.Max and Integer.Min as elements
3. check with Integer.Max+1 and Integer.Max-1
4. check with Integer.Min-1 and Integer.Min+1
5. duplicate elements
6. odd and even number of elements in array
7. array with different primitive type elements
8. check with all negative / all positive integers and mix of both
9. check length of array returned
10. array with only 1 element
11. check order of sorted array(asc/desc)
12. all zeroes
13. check with 0 at first or last index